# RegEx to get ALL Strings between two Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json, string

I seem to have a love/hate relationship with RegEx in that I love how incredibly powerful it is, but at the same time, I don't quite understand all of the nuances of it yet.

I've got rather lengthy JSON feed that I need to parse and capture ALL of the matches between two specific strings. I've included [a link to the regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/fU1iD1/2) with a few of the JSON results.

[regex101.com Example](https://regex101.com/r/fU1iD1/2)

I'm trying to match every string between each `/content/usergenerated` and `/jcr:content`

...

I guess what I should really be trying to match is a string that starts with `/content/webAppName/en/home` and ends **before** `/jcr:content`

The path that I care about will always start with `/content/webAppName/en/home`

Comment: Your regex is working, you just need to extract the first match from it, as seen in the `Match` panel on the right.

Comment: "I seem to have a love/hate relationship with RegEx": don't worry, this is the only true love.

Comment: My biggest issue that was identified below was that I wasn't using the global modifier. I feel pretty stupid about that mistake. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use "positive look-ahead" that match a sequence of digits if they are followed by something
https://regex101.com/r/fU1iD1/4

Comment: Your more compact version works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the two things you're looking to remove in parenthesis, and then remove them from the output. So...

`(\/content\/usergenerated)(.*)(\/jcr\:content)`

replaced by

`/2`

Which is everything in the middle of those two.

edit: Sorry, didn't look at your example :) - there was a deleted answer that said to add the g modifier, which looks like it works.

Comment: This works as well, though it returns more than I really need. Mulder90's response is what I should have been doing from the start. Nevertheless, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

/content/usergenerated/content/webAppName/en/home([a-zA-Z/-]+)/jcr:content

This should work.  It matches 3 out of 4 don't know why it doesn't match one of em.  You could use exec() in a loop till it returns null and get hold of the object[1] which contains data for the first and only capture group.

all the best.

PS: I used gmi in options for the regex.